# apache2 vhost error

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04

the error says:

```
Virtualhost mysite.com has no server environment set, request will not be honoured
```

my vhost file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  mysite.com

    ServerAdmin web@mysite.com

    DocumentRoot "/srv/d_servpa1/www/mysite.com/htdocs"
    <Directory "/srv/d_servpa1/www/mysite.com/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

ErrorLog /srv/d_servpa1/www/mysite.com/htdocs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

cant see why this isnt working

Comment: Can you please print out whats in the `error.log` and you apache modules? (`HTTPD -M`)

Comment: [Sun Sep 16 10:30:39 2012] [error] Virtualhost mysite.com has no server environment set, request will not be honoured.

Comment: Does the server use mpm_peruser_module?

Comment: i dont know, how can i know that?

Comment: You can see all apache loaded modules using
`apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep mpm_peruser_module`